# Code Signing Error: Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9, ipa

I am using **swift 4** with **Xcode 9**. My app run perfectly on the emulator. When I try to **Archive** for build **.ipa** file then only get this error. Is there any other way to share the app with a client?

```
Code Signing Error: The file "/Users/imran-mac/Desktop/Orlando Dev/njm-app-fiverr/NJM iOS/NJM/NO" could not be opened.
Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting for target "NJM" and build configuration "Release" is correct and that the file exists on disk.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'
```

[image]

Comment: You have to have an iOS developer account with Apple to have them download and test it without Xcode.

Comment: Thank you @Jake then how to share .ipa with other, what is the best way to share

Comment: You can have someone test it with Apple’s TestFlight.

Comment: If you don’t want to pay the $100 a year for the Apple developer account you could send them a zip of the file and walk them through downloading Xcode and running it on their device.

Comment: @Jake No, i never going that way. I just start development as soon as possible i will get a dev account :) thanks again